# add code for event listener for keypress in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to add an event listener for keypress after the CKEditor is loaded.
The code is something like:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.on('key', function(event) {
    /* instructions   */
});
```

Any idea where can I add the code for that? In which file or in what way?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Code to archive it is something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
        e.editor.on('contentDom', function() {
            e.editor.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
                // keyup event in ckeditor
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Edit - 2014 - Since this answer is still getting some upvotes, i felt it would be fair to point out, that it was meant for CKEditor in version 3.x. With the version 4.x there is a change event, which will trigger not only on key events but also after pasting, undo, redo etc.

In code its something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
    e.editor.on('change', function (event) {
        // change event in CKEditor 4.x
    });
});
```

Comment: Would this attach to every instance of CKEDITOR created?

Comment: @Chris yes if its set up before creating instances

Comment: Thanks @Zeela. It would be nice if there was a way to attach it to just one instance.

Comment: @Chris You can always use id of editor to find out which one made that event, i belive e.editor.id is index of CKEDITOR.instances, and e.editor.name will hold client id of the editor instance or its underlaying element, not sure which at this moment.

Comment: Can you please tell why it is not working for me?. I just replaced the 'instanceCreated' with the Id of the text area of my CKEDITOR, but still can´t see it working

Comment: @PabloQ Do i understand it correctly, that you want to add change event listener after the editor was created?

Answer (score 5):

Do you need to track changes?

I was originally using the solution above, but I ended up replacing it with the [OnChange CKEditor plugin](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html). This is useful in some special cases - for example, if you add a link using the toolbar, keypress won't register anything.

Here's a code example, updated to use instanceCreated (install OnChange first):

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
    if (e.editor.name === editorId) { //editorId is the id of the textarea
        e.editor.on('change', function(evt) {
            //Text change code
        });
    }
});
```

Update: According to the answer above, CKEditor now has a built-in change event, so you don't have to install the plugin to use this solution anymore. You can still use the second line of code to apply the change to the instance of CKEditor you want to edit.

Answer (score 1):

If the keydown logic makes sense for a given plugin, you can include it in the plugin's definition:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('customPlugin', {
    // definition keys...
    init: function( editor ) {
        // Plugin logic
        ...

    // Register a  keydown event handler -- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-key
    editor.on('key', function(event) {
        console.log('CKEDITOR keydown event from customPlugin'); // successfully captures keydown when registered from plugin
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested some of the solutions proposed here and I got my anwser when I found this link: http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html

The following code worked like a charm:

```
editor.on('contentDom', function()
{
    editor.document.on('keydown', function( event )
    {
        if ( !event.data.$.ctrlKey && !event.data.$.metaKey )
            somethingChanged();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('change', function () { //Do something here.});
```

This code registers any change event including copy-paste.

Comment: This code registers any change event including copy-paste.

Answer (score -2):

You add that code in your page, or in a .js file included in your page. There is no mystery about that code.

Comment: It's a long time ago but I think the downvoting is unfair and have "undone" one of them. The question was where to put the code, not about the code itself. Where else other than a js file included on the page or as js on the page would you put any ckEditor js code? I would agree though that the answer is a bit terse and not particularly helpful. I also note that @Gabriel cited a post by the same author in his answer (which doesn't mention where to put the code).