# If content in CKEditor is changed

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to detect if something is changed in a CKEditor using jquery, but can't get it to work.

```
 var isModified = false;

 $('textarea,input').change(function(){
      if(!isModified){
          isModified = true;
        }
 });

$(".ckeditor").document.on('keydown', function() {  isModified = true; });

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        $(".ckeditor").ckeditorGet().updateElement();

        if(isModified){
              return "Are you sure you want to leave page?";
           }
     };
```

Do anyone know what's needed in order to make it work for CKEditor 3.6.2? It works on all other form elements.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143516/detecting-onchange-events-from-a-ckeditor-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track changes within the editor by binding to the editor's key event.

Using the jQuery adapter:

```
$('.ckeditor').ckeditorGet().on('key', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.data.keyCode; // if you need to track the key
    isModified = true;
});
```

Docs on the [key](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#event%3akey) event

Comment: Note: some changes to the content might not be fired with a key event, for example making something bold is just a mouse clickety clack, not a single keyboard tap. Word.

Answer (score 30):

There is [a function called checkDirty() in the CKE api](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#checkDirty) for this. That way you don't need to roll your own. Also comes with other useful functions, like resetDirty(). Try this as a test:

```
if ( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.checkDirty() ) alert("Content changed");
```

**Update 5.7.2013**

See http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9794 - change event is a confirmed new feature! It has also been marked for Milestone 4.2 and confirmed by tweet from CKSource! Just don't trust the due date for milestones, they tend to change.

**Update 1.8.2013**

CKEditor 4.2 is out and it introduced the onChange event as a feature. Apparently it's not 100% reliable for every possible change according to the docs - hopefully it's good enough to use! Release info at http://ckeditor.com/release/CKEditor-4.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [CKEditor plugin](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html) that fires an event whenever the content changes.

Comment: for CKeditor 4.X?  And about @Nenotlep update, "CKEditor 4.2 is out and it introduced the onChange event as a feature", is the same or plugin is better?

Comment: It's a different implementation. Instead of picking the existing plugin and improving on it they decided to write a very basic version using the Undo, so they are missing all the features that I described when I explained why the Undo system in CKEditor is not enough for a change event.

Comment: The linked to page says it does not work and won't be updated for ckEditor 4.

Answer (score 0):

Checking with my local Drupal installation, CKEditor is not a regular HTML form element (it's not a textarea).  Rather, it is a IFrame mimicking a form element.  I think likely you will need to create a small CKEditor plugin shim and use that to communicate with your local scripts, see: [add code for event listener for keypress in ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386423/add-code-for-event-listener-for-keypress-in-ckeditor).