# trouble with CKEDITOR and a javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, function, replace, ckeditor

I've done a function in javascript that is able to change some abreviations by their expressions, all in javascript and onkeyup.

The trouble I met is that this does not work on a textarea that use the pluggin CKEDITOR,

when I disable ckeditor, it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var abbreviations = {
        "ABS": "Le débiteur est absent, nous le relançons par courrier. Nous agendons également une visite domiciliaire s'il s'avérait que ce dernier restait sans réponse.",




};

function abbrReplace(el, abbrs) {
    if (!el || !abbrs) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var val = el.value,
            words = val.split(/\s/);
        for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i<len; i++) {
            if (abbrs[words[i]]) {
                words[i] = abbrs[words[i]];
            }
        }
        return words.join(' ');
    }
}

document.getElementById("suivi").onkeyup = function(){
    this.value = abbrReplace(this, abbreviations);
};


</script>
```

I'm really lost, i've tried many thins to make this work.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Kind regards.

SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKeditor replaces your textarea with a CKeditor instance, and then ignores the textarea. What you're looking for is binding your function to CKeditor's keyup event and changing the editor's contents. Combining answers on [add code for event listener for keypress in ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386423/add-code-for-event-listener-for-keypress-in-ckeditor) and [How to find and replace text in CKEditor using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635118/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-ckeditor-using-javascript) results in something like this:

```
var abbreviations = ...;

function abbrReplace(el, abbrs) {
    ...changed to accept a piece of text instead of an element...
}

CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
    e.editor.on('contentDom', function() {
        e.editor.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
            // keyup event in ckeditor
            old_text = e.editor.getData();
            new_text = abbrReplace(old_text, abbreviations);
            e.editor.setData(new_text);
        });
    });
}); 

CKEDITOR.replace('suivi');
```

I've tested this and it doesn't work perfectly yet but it should point you in the right direction.