# jQuery CKEditor onKeyup

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I know this question has been asked quite a lot - but all the answers I've found are quite old, and don't seem to work (for me, at least).

I'm using the following code to do a live preview from an input box

```
$('#attractionName').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#preview-title').html($(this).val());
});
```

but obviously this doesn't work when using CKEditor. I found [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924145/using-jquery-to-grab-the-content-from-ckeditors-iframe) on the topic, but it doesn't seem to work for me. My textarea code is

```
<textarea name="tickets-TicketDescription" class="ckeditor" id="tickets-TicketDescription"></textarea>
```

Can *anyone* please can help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add code for event listener for keypress in ckeditor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386423/add-code-for-event-listener-for-keypress-in-ckeditor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CKEditor has built-in event system. You can add functions on events using "on" property in CKEditor configuration. There is an example for "key" event on CKEditor documentation page: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-on

Comment: Actually, the [editor#key](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-key) event is a binding to `keydown`, so it's a little bit different. Here's more adequate way (just replace `click` with `keydown`) http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom

Comment: Do I place this in `$(document).ready(function()` - or is `editor.on( 'contentDom', function()` replacing that?

Comment: Good point Reinmar. The "contentDom" event is "Fired when content of the editor (its DOM structure) is ready.  (...) It is also a first event fired after CKEDITOR.editable is initialized." - Tthat means you better place that code before the DOM is initialised, not in jQuery.ready(). Just put it somewhere in <script> tag. There are examples on CKEditor page how to make basic customisations: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-09-09-13-06/standard/samples/